# How to pass value between Activity and Fragment

Tags: java, android-activity, fragment

I am trying to pass value between activity and fragment But I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException. So please tell me how to
 do it in the right way. Here is my code:-

Activity class :-

```
String city = "one";
Fragmentone frag  = new Fragmentone(city);
```

And in Fragmentone class I am using something like this:-

```
String mcity ;
public Fragmentone(String city) {
this.mcity = city;

}

Log.e("--", mcity);
```

So this log is giving me NullPointerException

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting null pointer exception is because of this :

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument
>   constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class
>   when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able
>   to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument
>   constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some
>   cases during state restore.

**You cannot pass arguments through a constructor in fragment**.

For passing arguments, you should use `newInstance`.

In your case to pass `mcity` to fragment - `Fragmentone`, include this code in `Fragmentone`

```
String mCity;
public static newInstance(String mcity) {
    Fragmentone fragmentOne = new Fragmentone();
    Bundle argumentsBundle = new Bundle();
    argumentsBundle.putString("mcityKey", mcity);
    fragmentOne.setArguments(argumentsBundle);
    return fragmentOne;
}

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        String mCity = getArguments().getString("mcityKey");
        Log.i("city : ", mcity);
        }
```

Now in activity class you can do this,

```
String city = "one"; 
Fragmentone frag  = new Fragmentone(city);
```

[see more examples and details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)